# Unable to access using windows authentication on Telerik Sitefinity 4.1

Tags: telerik, sitefinity, sitefinity-4

I've to enable SSO authentication on a Sitefinity application that before was using Form Authentication with a custom provider.

I've enabled it in the web.config

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
  <!--<forms slidingExpiration="true" name="xxx.ASPXAUTH" cookieless="UseCookies" requireSSL="false" ticketCompatibilityMode="Framework20" timeout="180" />-->
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

And when I try to access to a page I got the domain popup to appear. I insert mine credential but I go again the domain popup

[image]

I've cross checked everything but everything seems ok... what can be the reason I can't logon? and it falls me back as I've entered a wrong password?